# HTTP 500 error using Azure Easytables with Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, azure

Having created a mobile app in Azure using EasyTables with a Node.js backend, I get an HTTP 500 error trying to post a new item.

Comment: For me the server dies as soon as an easy table is created... the website is reachable if I delete the easy table then gone again once I add one.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the Azure console and in the project backend run:

```
npm i sqlite3
```

That fixes it.

(Answering my own question because I couldn't find this anywhere on StackOverflow. Props to @benjamintam from Readify for the solution)

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile app application is running on Azure cloud not on locally, the issue is a little odd, as the sqlite 3 supporting is for Azure Mobile Apps development on local. You can refer to https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_configuration_DataProviders.html for the detailed description.

If your issue occurs on your Mobile Apps running on Azure, please double check whether you have completed the project's initialization. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/#configure-the-server-project for the steps.

Meanwhile, you can manually add the data connection to Azure SQL in the Azure portal,
[image]

And if successfully, you can find the configuration `MS_TableConnectionString` in Application settings in your Mobile Apps.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.